# Kitchen ceiling light

Tags: wiring

I am trying to wire a kitchen light fixture to an outlet box located in the ceiling. There are four black wires with only one of them being hot. There are four neutrals and a ground. When I tried to wire all for the black together, this breaker kept tripping. I need to Know what combination would work best for wiring this light fixture but I have no idea what the other wires connect to.

Comment: Show us your "before" pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Many different possibilities. Before I give the example, please write the following on the chalkboard 100 times:

- *Neutral is always white. But white is not always neutral.*

And now, a possible answer:

Cables in the US with two wires (ignoring bare ground) are black and white. Almost always, at least for 12 AWG (15A or 20A) and 14 AWG (15A) circuits. The same cables are used for:

- 120V hot/neutral to power an unswitched receptacle, a built-in appliance with its own built-in switch, etc.
- 240V hot/hot to power a 240V appliance (e.g., water heater)
- 120V switched hot/neutral to power a switched light or other device
- An old-style *switch loop*

This last one is important here. A common setup (I have some in my 1950s house) is to have hot/neutral go to a light fixture junction box. Then white goes down as hot to the switch box (yes, white, even though it is *not* neutral) and black comes back up from the switch box to the light fixture as switched hot. The white wire is supposed to be marked to indicate it is hot and not neutral, but that is not always done (or tape falls off, etc.).

Which means you *may* have:

- One cable from the panel hot black/neutral white
- One cable to the switch hot white/switched hot black
- Two cables to other devices hot black/neutral white

In order to figure this out, you have to figure out where each wire is going.

The first cable is easy: The one which is hot when all the wires are disconnected but the breaker is on is the one coming from the panel.

With the breaker off or the hot wire capped for safety:

- Turn the light switch on
- Use a multimeter to check for continuity in each of the other pairs of black/white wires
- Since certain situations (ask me how I know...) can result in a multimeter showing continuity when you might not expect it, when you *think* you have found the right cable turn *off* the switch and see if continuity goes away. If it does, you found the switch loop cable. If it doesn't, keep hunting.

Now that you have the switch loop identified, connect:

- Panel hot black to switch loop hot white. Mark the white wire with black tape.
- Panel white neutral to light fixture neutral
- Switch loop switched hot black to light fixture hot
- Turn the switch off
- Turn on the breaker
- Test the switch and light fixture

Assuming that works, turn the breaker off again and then, one cable at a time (to minimize problems in case there really is a short circuit somewhere), connect hot black to panel hot black *and* switch loop hot white, and also connect neutral white to panel neutral white *and* light fixture neutral. Turn the breaker back on and make sure everything still works - now including at least one receptacle or other device that wasn't working before.